# Problem with same output of if and else statements

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have started programming a week week ago, and was stuck in an if else related problem. The code i wrote was :-

```
Console.WriteLine("hello, what is your username?");
  string name = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("hi, " + name + " nice to meet you!");
    
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your password");
   string password = Console.ReadLine();
   if (password == "blablabla")
   {
    Console.WriteLine("you are signed in");
   }
   else;{
    Console.WriteLine("incorrect password");}
```

And, at the output, even if i put the right password, it shows "you are signed in" as well as "incorrect password". Please tell me what am I doing wrong, thanks :)

Comment: The pronlem is here `else;`<--. `else` is terminated and next block `{
    Console.WriteLine("incorrect password");}` is *always* executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should delete the ; that comes after the else
good luck

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma "; " from else; that will